# Imported 'soap' is undefined

Tags: node.js, node-soap

I installed a package called [`soap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap).

This is in src/index.ts:

```js
import soap from "soap";

console.log(soap);
```

I'm using ts-node-dev to compile and run.

```bash
tsnd --respawn src/index.ts
>>> undefined
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Why is `soap` undefined, even though I'm able to go to the definition in my IDE?

Comment: What is `soap` supposed to be? Are you sure it's imported correctly? Is the package installed?

Comment: The package is installed. It's also present in my node_modules.

Comment: Shouldn't that `import soap from "soap";`  be `import * as soap from "soap";`? Or perhaps you might want to only import specific parts of the module like `import { createClient } from "soap";`

Comment: That worked, thanks! My initial approach was based on the docs: https://github.com/dderevjanik/wsdl-tsclient